# How to get 'overall' numbers in forest plot in meta analysis using STATA

Tags: stata, meta-analysis, forest-plot

I am trying to perform a meta-analysis. I put together the data, and I am creating a forest plot. I have several questions regarding how I can change the figure created by STATA.

1- After the studies are summarized in the forest plot, at the bottom there is "overall" section. However, in this section, the studies above are not summarized (in terms of total number, yes/no etc.) How can I add these numbers here?
2- By default, STATA creates "log odds ratio" and its 95% CI. I would like to use "odds ratio" here. I tried "meta forestplot, eform(Odds ratios)", and was able to get odds ratio here as shown in the attached picture. However, I couldn't find this option in statistics>meta-analysis section (plus I need to edit the graph further, and when I use this code I don't know how to edit it further). If this options exists in statistics>meta-analysis section, can you please help me find it?
3- How can I add 'year' after author names (study)?
4- [image: I am attaching an edited picture to better express my problems.]

I'd really appreciate your help.

Best,
Baha

Comment: You could try Statalist